# Spatial Hashing to find closest pair of points from input file C++

Tags: c++, hash, spatial

I have a homework assignment and have no idea where to start or what to do. Basically, I need to organize roughly 1 million points using "Spatial Hashing" and use the hash table to find two points that are closest to each other, and return the distance.

Assignment Specifics are:
To find the closest pair of points quickly, you will divide the unit square containing the points into a b×b grid of square “cells”, each representing a 2D square of size 1/b×1/b.  Each point should be“hashed” to the cell containing it.  For example, if you are storing the x coordinate of a point in a“double” variable named x, then(int)(x * b)will scale the coordinate up by b and round down to the nearest integer; the result (in the range 0. . . b−1) can be used as an one of the indices into your 2D array of cells.  The other index is calculated the same way, only using they coordinate. After hashing, each point needs only to be compared to the other points within its cell, and the 8 cells immediately surrounding its cell – this should result in many fewer comparisons than if we simply compared every point to every other point.  You will need to select an appropriate value of1
bas part of this lab exercise.  You may want to consider what are the dangers in setting b too low or too high. Internally, the grid of cells should be stored as a 2-dimensional array of pointers to linked lists, with each linked list containing the set of points belonging to a single cell.  The array of cells must be dynamically allocated (with the new command) and subsequently de-allocated at the end of your program (with the delete) command.  This means that, since each cell of the table is itself a pointer to a node of a linked list, the top-level variable representing the 2D array of pointers will be of type “Node ***” (with three *’s!), assuming “Node” is the name of the structure representing a node in your linked lists.

Your program should consist of the following major steps:

1. Allocate and initialize 2D array of pointers to linked lists.
2. Read input file, inserting each point into the appropriate linked list based on the cell to which it maps.
3. For each point, compare it to all the points within its cell and the 8 adjacent cells; remember the smallest distance obtained during this process.
4. De-allocate 2D array and linked lists.
5. Print out minimum distance.
   Part  of  this  lab  also  involves  figuring  out  a  good  choice  for  the  value  of b.   Please  include  in  a comment in your code a brief description of why you think your choice of b is a good one.

Comment: I would start with google. Google "spatial hashing" brought some promising hits on the first page incl. [Quadtree vs Spatial Hashing - a Visualization](http://zufallsgenerator.github.io/2014/01/26/visually-comparing-algorithms/) - funny, as this was my first thought: "How about quad trees? What's the difference to spatial hashing? (Is there a difference?)" - I'm afraid your question is too broad for this site. Instead, specific code questions (at best with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) are expected.

Comment: I think the assignment is pretty clear. Maybe you read too much into "hash". In the assignment, it just means "convert to a number". If you have trouble with this, then I guess you will need to first refresh what is an array, what is a linked list, how to read from a file, how to calculate distances.